# MacBook Pro will not detect monitor until the cord is unplugged/replugged from the monitor itself

Tags: macbook-pro, display, hdmi

My MacBook Pro 2017 (running macOS Sierra 10.12.5) won't detect my [monitor](http://www.samsung.com/us/computing/monitors/curved/34-ultra-wide-curved-screen-monitor-ls34e790cns-za/) until I've unplugged and replugged the cord ONLY into the monitor itself. The cord is a USB-C to HDMI cord.

**Things I've tried that haven't worked:** Turning the monitor off/on, opening/closing the Mac with the cord in.

Anyone have any thoughts on how I could fix this issue? At the moment every time I plug my Mac into my monitor I have to pull my monitor to the front of my desk and unplug/replug the cord into the monitor.

Comment: Does this problem exist with other monitors?

Comment: @Jackson1442 hm, seems to be only this monitor (just checked with another one).

Comment: It looks like this is a problem with the monitor itself.Just to confirm, you are using the same cord and setup with the other monitor you tried?

Comment: @Jackson1442 yeah, same cord. Definitely looking like it's an issue with the monitor.

Comment: can you try plugging a different computer into the monitor? Preferably Windows, using USB C